# Scrapy logs display twice after install coloredlogs

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy logs display twice after install coloredlogs. I used following code in scrapy's settings.py.

```
import logging, coloredlogs
coloredlogs.install()
```

Comment: can you try moving this code to some `__init__.py` file in your project instead? It's possible that in `settings.py` it's executed twice.